# Simplifying Lists

Tags: python, simplify, simplification

How Can This Code Be Simplified? That is the question.

```
    stat_keys.append(self.request.get("stat_one"))
    stat_keys.append(self.request.get("stat_two"))
    stat_keys.append(self.request.get("stat_three"))
    stat_keys.append(self.request.get("stat_four"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stat_keys += [self.request.get(k) for k in ('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four')]
```

or

```
stat_keys += map(self.request.get, ('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four')))
```

or

```
map(stat_keys.append, map(self.request.get, ('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four')))
```

I suggest the first one, though.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without knowing what any of the variables are, but how about this:

```
for stat in ('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four'):
    stat_keys.append(self.request.get(stat))
```

Or, using a generator expression:

```
[stat_keys.append(self.request.get(stat)) for stat in ('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to `.extend()` with a generator expression:

```
stat_keys.extend(self.request.get(stat) for stat in('stat_one', 'stat_two', 'stat_three', 'stat_four'))
```

Comment: Assuming that `stat_keys` supports `extend`, which we don't know from the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
s_list = [ "stat_one", "stat_two", "stat_three", "stat_four" ]
[ stat_keys.append(self.request.get(s)) for s in s_list ]
```